# Backgrounds not loading in chrome using HTML 5

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, background

So I've been working with creating a HTML 5 layout based off of this template: http://html5up.net/big-picture

Problem is when I mess around with the order of the sections the background images of certain sections disappear - it's still perfectly visible in Firefox but not in Chrome. Sometimes if you refresh the page the images appear.

The website in question is here: http://melissafionda.com

I thought that simply reordering the sections in css and javascript would be the solution but that hasn't fixed it.

The CSS looks like this for each section but obviously with different names for the images:

```
    #intro {        
    background: url('../images/overlay.png'), url('../images/intro.jpg');
    background-size: 256px 256px, cover;
    background-attachment: fixed, fixed;
    background-position: top left, bottom center;
    background-repeat: repeat, no-repeat;
}
```

This is a part of the HTML where the background section fails to load:

```
            <section id="four" class="main style3 primary">
            <div class="content container">
            <div class="box container small">
                <header>
                    <h2>Zero-G</h2>
                    <p>Zero-G is a small rogue-like game where you play as a scavenger robot collecting materials in abandonned stations. The video below was just the introductory video. Background, logo model and design and character textures all done by myself. Animations by Conor Doyle and Kieran Gates, Character Model by Matthew Seprini.

            </div>
            </br></br>
                    <iframe src="//player.vimeo.com/video/94031161?title=0&amp;byline=0&amp;portrait=0" width="1000" height="565" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe></br></br>
                </header>


                <footer>
                    <a href="#three" class="button style2 down">More</a>
                </footer>                           

            </div>
        </section>
```

Comment: I followed your link and opened up the console. There's an error: **Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://melissafionda.com/images/overlay.png**

Comment: No problem on Chrome 36 and Opera 21.